# Using calculated columns in future calculations sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I generated a column with the following calculation:

```
SELECT b.[CUSIP NUMBER],
       b.[ORIGINAL BALANCE],
       b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY],
       b. [PASS THRU RATE],
       b.[ORIGINAL BALANCE] * ( ( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12 ) * ( 1 + power (( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12),  b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY] ) ) / ( 1 + (power (( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12 ), b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY] )))) Monthlypayment
FROM   DBO.mbs012013 a,
       dbo.mbs022013 b
WHERE  a.[CUSIP NUMBER] = b.[CUSIP NUMBER]
```

I would like to use the calculated column "MonthlyPayment" in a new calculation. How do I reference it in the new calculation? When I write Select [MonthlyPayment] the program does not understand the reference. Is it possible to use these calculated columns in future calculations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not permitted directly. You can define the alias at another level though. I tend to use `CROSS APPLY` in [cases where it is permitted](http://sqlmag.com/blog/tip-apply-and-reuse-column-aliases) (as here). If using window functions in the expression the `APPLY` method does not work however.

```
SELECT b.[CUSIP NUMBER],
       b.[ORIGINAL BALANCE],
       b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY],
       b. [PASS THRU RATE],
       Monthlypayment,
       Monthlypayment2
FROM   DBO.mbs012013 a
       JOIN dbo.mbs022013 b
         ON a.[CUSIP NUMBER] = b.[CUSIP NUMBER]
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT b.[ORIGINAL BALANCE] * ( ( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12 ) * ( 1 + power (( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12 ), b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY]) ) / ( 1 + ( power (( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12 ), b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY]) ) ) )) CA(Monthlypayment)
       CROSS APPLY(SELECT 1 + Monthlypayment) CA2(Monthlypayment2)
```

Comment: Thank you again. You're on a roll today Marty!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean in the same query.  The answer is yes.  You need to use a CTE (`with` statement) or subquery:

```
select *
from (SELECT b.[CUSIP NUMBER],
             b.[ORIGINAL BALANCE],
             b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY],
             b. [PASS THRU RATE],
             b.[ORIGINAL BALANCE] * ( ( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12 ) * ( 1 + power (( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12),  b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY] ) ) / ( 1 + (power (( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12 ), b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY] )))) Monthlypayment
      FROM   DBO.mbs012013 a join
             dbo.mbs022013 b
             on a.[CUSIP NUMBER] = b.[CUSIP NUMBER]
     ) t
```

I also fixed your join syntax to use the much preferable `on` clause.

If you want it available to other queries, then consider creating a view with this column.  Just put `create view <some name> as` before the definition.

Comment: Your code is coming in hot today Gordon! Thank you! Super Job!